# Any documentation on how to configure multiple/2 domain for one amazon lightsail instance

Tags: multiple-domains, amazon-lightsail

I need to set up two domain from godaddy to one instance of lightsail.

I already configure two hotzones, one for the example.com domain and the other for the example2.com domain.

The example.com is loading well, but I get the DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN on the second one.

I already updated the DNS on godaddy.

I modify the vhost with the two domains.

I have try to have one  hotzone and a domain and subdomain and I havent been able to load the example2.com domain.

Answer (score 1):

1. Move your DNS Management to Lightsail DNS Zone
2. Create static IP for your instance
3. Update your **A Record**  pointing to your static IP
4. Follow this for all two Domains
5. Now your two domains point same Static IP which has a one instance

Comment: No need to get static ip either, you can directly point to instance. and inside instance configure server accordingly.

Comment: @Arunkumar were you able to resolve it? My second Domain is not working on the same instance. Here is what I did: 1) Created second zone and copied its name server to my DNS provider 2) Added A record '@.xyz.com' and 'www.xyz.com' in the new DNS Zone but I'm still unable to access the website.

Comment: @MayankTiwari do you have any more details about that, please share here! I'll really appreciate such help of yours.

Comment: @Umar https://tutorialsjoint.com/multiple-domain-apps-on-same-lightsail-instance/ I created a tutorial on my blog for this.

Comment: Hello, I fix it by going to DNS configuration in each domain in godaddy and set the static ip of the instance of ligthsail. That help me instead of doing the DNZ zone for each domian in AWS. It worked great.  So for one instance I now have X number of domians pointing to it, not subdomains. Thanks.